# How to get data array from json response exclude header in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

Hi I create a small Laravel getter as below.

```
public function getYearListAttribute(){
    $presentyear = intval($this->created_at->format('Y'));
    $myarray[] = array(
        'present' => $presentyear, 
        'past1' => $presentyear-1,
        'past2' => $presentyear-2,
        'past3' => $presentyear-3
    ); 
    return response()->json($myarray); 
}
```

I call its from blade like this.

```
{{$mymodel->yearlist}}
```

But I received response with header instead only array list.

```
 HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, private Content-Type: application/json Date: Sun, 12 Jul 2020 02:05:44 GMT [{"present":2020,"past1":2019,"past2":2018,"past3":2017}]
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can return response like below

```
return response()->json($myarray)->getContent()
```

it will return only data

Comment: Dear Monika, getData() not work but getContent() worked. But print result [{"present":2020,"past1":2019,"past2":2018,"past3":2017}] action like plain text instead array. I can not access like {{ count($myModel->yearlist)}} (Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable).

Comment: what is the purpose of `{{ count($myModel->yearlist)}}`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any situation where you'd want to return a complete HTTP response from a Model accessor. Generally, models do not initiate request/response changes, as this is typically done via a Route > Controller (AJAX or otherwise). In this particular case, you can simply return your variable:

```
public function getYearlistAttribute() {
  $presentYear = intval($this->created_at->format('Y'));

  $myArray[] = [
    'present' => $presentYear, 
    'past1' => $presentYear-1,
    'past2' => $presentYear-2,
    'past3' => $presentYear-3
  ]; 

  return $myArray;
}
```

The response of `{{ $myModel->yearlist }}` will now simply be your defined array, not an HTTP response.

Edit: But of course you cannot simply do `{{ $myModel->yearlist }}`, as that is an array. You'll need to loop it:

```
@foreach($myModel->yearlist as $key => $year)
  {{ "{$key} - {$year}" }} // `present - 2020`, `past1 - 2019`, etc...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Dear, Tim Lewis. Already tried but not work. I can not printout on blade, got an error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string.

Comment: Right, you've got an array... You can't do `{{ $myModel->yearlist }}`, you need to loop it: `@foreach($myModel->yearlist as $year) {{ $year }} @endforeach`.